# Disambiguation of [mobile-operators] and [phone-networks] tags

Tags: support, tagging

If we need [phone-networks](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phone-networks) (11 Open Qs) as well as [mobile-operators](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile-operators) (33 Open Qs), the latter with a Usage guide of:

> The companies which provide cellphone / mobile phone services around the world.

Could someone please explain why? ([phone-networks](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phone-networks) has no Usage guide).

I appreciate "operators" might cover the likes of O2, EE, Three Mobile, Vodafone, Mobile by Sainsbury's, Virgin Media, giffgaff, Tesco Mobile etc (that Google finds me from a search of *phone networks*) and that [phone-networks](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phone-networks) might be more the likes of 1G, 2G, 3G, 3.5G, 3.75G, 4G, LTE etc. but it seems the tags are not used in this way at present on TSE.

Maybe also GSM-850, GSM-900, EGSM/EGSM-900, GSM-1800, GSM-1900 and UMTS are relevant.

---

[cellphones](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cellphones)
[communication](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communication)
[data-plans](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-plans)
[gsm](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gsm)
[international-calls](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-calls)
[internet](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet)
[mobile-apps](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile-apps)
[mobile-internet](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile-internet)
[phone](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phone)
[roaming](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roaming)
[wifi](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi)
 *might* be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The companies are usually known as Mobile Network Operators (MNO), which generally operate one mobile network per country. (That is to say, Vodafone doesn't have a global mobile network, it has many national networks).

Companies like "Mobile by Sainsbury" do not operate networks; they're basically resellers. As such, they're known as virtual operators (MVNO).

2G, 3G, LTE etc are examples of mobile phone *Standards* .

BTW, the "gps navigation" tag is entirely unrelated.

Comment: 3G is not a standard but a marketing term; the standard is called UMTS.

Comment: @gerrit By the same token, UMTS is only one family of 3G standards, EVDO being the other, though UMTS was always much more widely deployed.